# Use XmlSerializer to add a namespace without a prefix

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I want my output to look like this

```
<OrderContainer xmlns="http://blabla/api/products" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

So I added the following to my XmlSerializer

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderContainer));
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "http://blabla/api/products");
ns.Add("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
// do stuff..
x.Serialize(stream, orderContainer, ns);
```

But now I get

```
<OrderContainer xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

So how do I edit the default namespace?

---

My object definition is like:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="OrderContainer", Namespace="http://blabla/api/products")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class OrderContainer
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [XmlSerializer constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw0f5wee.aspx) which takes a default namespace in addition to the type you want to serialize:

```
var x = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(OrderContainer), 
    "http://blabla/api/products");
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
x.Serialize(stream, orderContainer, ns);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `[XmlElementAttribute]`, not `[DataContractAttribute]`, if you wish to use the XML Serializer.

Comment: Yes, it were just some WCF generated entities; so they were decorated with the `DataContractAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, had to use `DataContractSerializer`, which automatically generates correct XML, including the namespaces.

```
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(OrderContainer));
//do stuff..
dcs.WriteObject(s, orderContainer);
```